# Print Method Calls

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-api

I am trying to print a list of all method calls to the standard output, with information about which method was called, and which method called it. I am trying to do this using the Eclipse API, does anyone know any functions that could be capable of giving me this information?

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you need to print this information, you can try the below:

```
Exception ex = new Exception("");
ex.printStacktrace();
```

The point is, do not throw the Exception, just print the Stack Trace :-)